# How to install apt packages?

Tags: apt, command-line, python

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 machine. I had accidentally removed Python2.7.2 which I've sorted now, GUI is running and all other commands like easy_install, pip are working.

But when I type **any** apt commands like apt-get, apt-cache I get following error:

> /usr/bin/python: can't find '_ _main _ _' module in
>   '/usr/share/command-not-found'

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are probably missing the command-not-found and command-not-found-data packages, try reinstalling these, if you cant reinstall them with apt-get, try using aptitude if you already have it installed.

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Adding to @nisshh's suggestion: if you have no aptitude installed, you could try downloading the packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ([command-not-found](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/command-not-found) plus [command-not-found-data](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/command-not-found-data)) and install them manually using `sudo dpkg -i command*.deb`

Comment: Thanks everyone I have solved it. Basically it would give me same(given above) error no matter what try. So I logged out and pressed ALT+CTRL+F1 to enter tty1. There all the apt commands worked. Once I logged back in, I had issues with PATH variable which I had to export.

Comment: Sounds like this is resolved. Please submit an answer and mark your question as answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone I have solved it.

Basically it would give me same error (error given above) no matter what try. 
So I logged out and pressed `ALT+CTRL+F1` to enter `tty1`. There all the apt commands worked. Once I logged back in, I had issues with `PATH` variable which I had to export

Comment: a little more detail with how you made the export would make the answer more helpful...

Comment: Export scripts on a .bashrc file and load it on startup. Anyway exporting PATH variables is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: sorry.. my ignorance..